# Problems while sharing files from my data drive

Tags: 14.04, permissions, samba

This is my first post after switching to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, desktop version, for my media server.

I am having problems creating share on an extra drive.

I can create and access shares on the system drive. But I have added a 2nd drive to hold my data (will probably RAID in the near future) however when I create a share using the GUI on this drive it is inaccessible and i keep getting access denied errors. Can anyone shed any light on what i am doing wrong?

All the permission and share settings are the same. I have also tried changing the permissions on the folder containing the shared folder but this doesn't have any effect

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem. 
I had to give 'other' execute permission on all folders from the root to the shared directory.

I.e the share was located at /media/pau/data/share, I had to give 'other' execute permisson on /media, /media/paul, /media/paul/data